# How to build or import a npm-package from create-react-app with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to export my react-project as an npm package.
I'm using create-react-app to build a production build. I also followed this (https://medium.com/@revanth0212/how-to-create-and-publish-react-components-using-the-create-react-app-9d60583c2161) article to publish it to npm. Now I have no idea how to import the exported classes. 
I tried nwb to build a package, too. I could build and import the example from their site, but I can't compile my project. 
It uses typescript

The code of the index.js is:

```js
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';

export {
    DateEditor
}
from './component/editor/DateEditor';

export {
    CellClassProvider
}
from './component/cellClassProvider/CellClassProvider';

export {
    DateEditor
}
from './component/editor/DateEditor';

export {
    TextAreaEditor
}
from './component/editor/TextAreaEditor';

export {
    BooleanFilter
}
from './component/filter/BooleanFilter';

export {
    DateFormatter
}
from './component/formatter/DateFormatter';

export {
    NumberFormatter
}
from './component/formatter/NumberFormatter';

export {
    Formatter
}
from './component/formatter/Formatter';

export {
    BooleanRenderer
}
from './component/renderer/BooleanRenderer';

exports.blub = function () {
    console.log('blub');
};
```

This doesn't work:

```
import {BooleanRenderer} from 'entitytable'
```

And with nwb i get those errors:

```
 ERROR  in ./src/component/renderer/BooleanRenderer.tsx 4:52
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:52)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import { CommandInvoker } from "../../action/command/CommandInvoker";
|
> export class BooleanRenderer extends React.Component<{ data: any, colDef: any, value: boolean }, { data: any, column: string, value: boolean }> {
|
|     constructor(props: Readonly<{ data: any, colDef: any, value: boolean }>) {
 @ ./src/index.js 29:0-75 29:0-75
 @ multi ./src/index.js
```

**Edit**

The package is called entitytable and is hosted as an artifact on an azure server.
My main problem is, that I don't understand, how to import the minified package.
I build it with create-react-app and published the minified build as npm-package on the azure server. I can import it with require('entitytable') in another project. But I can't import the exported classes (like DateFormatter)

**Edit 2**

Some more error-messages:
After I followed the article above (https://medium.com/@revanth0212/how-to-create-and-publish-react-components-using-the-create-react-app-9d60583c2161) I get this error:

```
./node_modules/entitytable/dist/api/DynamicsApi.ts 6:33
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:33)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import DynamicsWebApi from 'dynamics-web-api';
|
> export default class DynamicsApi implements Api {
|     private static readonly WEB_API_URL: string = 'http://172.16.253.54/DRieke/api/data/v8.2/';
|     private readonly dynamicsWebApi = new DynamicsWebApi({ webApiUrl: DynamicsApi.WEB_API_URL, includeAnnotations: "*" });
```

Comment: Hi @worsty,

Welcome and thanks for your question. At this moment it is a bit hard to understand your problem. There are missing some information. For example, could yo tell us how your package is called on npm? Is it `entitytable`? Is your project hosted on github or bitbucket or gitlab? It could also be, that you need to transpile your code from jsx to valid js code. There are many options how to help, but first get more specific and give us more information about your exact setup otherwise it will be hard to help. Good luck!